# Why doesn't this midpoint line algorithm draw vertical lines (or diagonals that approach the vertical)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I implemented this algorithm I found online, and it draws horizontal lines and half of all diagonals just fine.  But as the diagonal line passes the "halfway" mark to becoming vertical, it doesn't update y and only draws the line with a smaller slope.  It does draw it all the way to x2, but draws a line sloped to a different y2 coordinate.  And if you try to draw a vertical line, nothing is drawn.  Can anyone find the bug?

```
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0);
}

void midPoint(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    if (x1 > x2)
    {
        midPoint(x2, y2, x1, y1);
        return;
    }

    int slope;
    int dx, dy, d, x, y;

    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = y2 - y1;
    d = dx - 2 * dy;
    y = y1;

    if (dy < 0) {
        slope = -1;
        dy = -dy;
    }
    else {
        slope = 1;
    }

    for (x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        if (d <= 0) {
            d += 2 * dx - 2 * dy;
            y += slope;
        }
        else {
            d += -2 * dy;
        }
        glEnd();
    }

}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    midPoint(10, 10, 110, 210);

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    midPoint(10, 10, 210, 110);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    midPoint(210, 10, 10, 110);

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Bresenham\'s midpoint line algorithm");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is Bresenham's algorithm, then you should look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: Well, your `for` loop only does one pixel per x value.  Is it really a surprise it can't handle lines closer to vertical than to horizontal?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're doing this line-drawing by explicitly drawing individual pixels using Bresenham, instead of just telling OpenGL to draw the line?  If the goal is just to draw a line, that'd be a lot simpler.  :)

Comment: Michael Abarash released a bunch of books and articles on how to handle all these cases - way back when we were using VGA graphics cards.

Answer (score 3):

Bresenham's line drawing algorithm can't plot vertical lines.
To plot vertical line use DDA line drawing algorithm. But the problem with DDA is that, it won't be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Optimization) the implementation would look like:

```
void midPoint(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    bool steep = abs(y2 - y1) > abs(x2 - x1);
    if(steep) {
        // swap x1 and y1
        int tmp = x1;
        x1 = y1;
        y1 = tmp;
        // swap x2 and y2
        tmp = x2;
        x2 = y2;
        y2 = tmp;
    }
    if(x1 > x2) {
        // swap x1 and x2
        int tmp = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = tmp;
        // swap y1 and y2
        tmp = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = tmp;
    }

    int dx, dy, error, ystep, y;

    dx = x2 - x1;
    dy = abs(y2 - y1);
    error = dx / 2;
    y = y1;

    if(y1 < y2)
        ystep = 1;
    else
        ystep = -1;

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (x = x1; x <= x2; x++) {
        if(steep)
            glVertex2f(y, x);
        else
            glVertex2f(x, y);
        error -= dy;
        if (error < 0) {
            y += ystep;
            error += dx;
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

(couldn't test yet but fixed in regard to aschepler's comment)

Comment: Notice the sentence: "The algorithm will be initially presented only for the octant in which the segment goes down and to the right (x0≤x1 and y0≤y1), and its horizontal projection  is longer than the vertical projection  (the line has a negative slope whose absolute value is less than 1.)"

Comment: You are absolutely right, atm it doesn't work if the line is "steep", saw it too late

Comment: This almost works.  Except, when you draw a line that passes over the diagonal threshold towards vertical, it shifts the line over sometimes in the x direction, sometimes in the y direction, sometimes both.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem and solution seems quiet simple.The while loop is the key to get the vertical line rendered correctly.

The code below is code from my graphics project with Java. z coordinate is for z buffer.

Notice that the loop runs dx times when sampling is along x-axis and it runs dy times when sampling is along y-axis

```
display.setColor(Color.BLACK);
dx=x2-x1;
dy=y2-y1;

if(dx<0)
    xinc=-1;
else
    xinc=1;
if(dy<0)
    yinc=-1;
else
    yinc=1;
zinc=z2-z1;


dx=Math.abs(dx);dy=Math.abs(dy);
if(dx>dy){
    zinc/=dx;
    dy=dy<<1;
    p=dy-dx;
    y2=dx;
    dx=dx<<1;

    display.drawPixel(x1, y1, z1);
    for(j=0;j<y2;j++){
        z1+=zinc;
        if(p>=0){
            p-=dx;
            y1+=yinc;
        }
        x1+=xinc;
        p+=dy;
        display.drawPixel(x1, y1, z1);
    }


}
else{
    zinc/=dy;
    dx=dx<<1;
    p=dx-dy;
    x2=dy;
    dy=dy<<1;
    display.drawPixel(x1, y1, z1);
    for(j=0;j<x2;j++){
        z1+=zinc;
        if(p>=0){
            p-=dy;
            x1+=xinc;
        }
        y1+=yinc;
        p+=dx;
        //System.out.println("Pixel : "+x1+" ,"+y1);
        display.drawPixel(x1, y1, z1);
    }
}
```